# What cause the error "Row 'c1408' infeasible, all entries at implied bounds."? How can I display it in matlab?

Tags: matlab, linear-programming, cplex

I ran into this problem when I tried to use `cplexmiqp` in `matlab` to solve a unit commitment problem.

I have a lot of constraints but I carefully checked all the constraints, they should be fine. I don't know where this error came from and I tried to display the row 1408 but I don't know how to do that.

Has anyone encountered the same problem before? And does anybody know how to solve it?

Answer (score 2):

The usual way to display the model using `cplex.writeModel() API.`

```
 cplex.writeModel('<your_miqp_proble_filename>.lp');
```

However, if you are using the Optimization Toolbox (to invoke CPLEX from inside MATLAB) there appears to be another option you could try: `ExportModel` (Note: I haven't used this option.)

[From CPLEX for MATLAB](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/cosinfoc/v12r5/index.jsp?topic=%2Filog.odms.cplex.help%2FCPLEX%2FMATLAB%2Ftopics%2Fgs_param.html):

> The parameter ExportModel (or exportmodel) takes a file name as an
>   argument. The default is the empty string (""). For example, opt =
>   cplexoptimset('exportmodel', 'myModel.lp');can be used to set the name
>   of the exported model.

You can open an `LP` file that contains your problem, look at the constraints and see if they are all as you intended them.

I'd also suggest that you iteratively make your problem smaller (fewer rows/columns.) If the problem continues to recur, you can diagnose it much quicker. If it doesn't, then the problem was in one of the things you dropped recently.

Hope that helps you move forward.